# JMS implementation in AEM/CQ5

Tags: aem

I have a requirement in which we need to send email from AEM using cq mail service. But the problem is we need to implement it JMS queue so that it doesn't overburden the server. So is there any document how can we integrate JMS queue into AEM.

Comment: By saying "doesn't overburden the server" , are you trying to reduce load on AEM server while sending email from it ? Would like to know in what situation , you are considering to integrate JMS queue .

Comment: @Sabya Yes u r correct, I don't want to overburden AEM server. Because ours is ticket booking site, so there will be thousands of mail triggered simultaneously. So I want to integrate JMS queue for sending emails asynchronously, so that it doesn't overburden the AEM server.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Sling Eventing](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/apache-sling-eventing-and-job-handling.html)? This can be integrated into AEM pretty easily!